# Help identifying a 4-lead component marked P&V 100487

Tags: identification, components, repair, markings

The following components have the same identification marking and the same properties as far as I know. The component is part of an diesel electrical generator controller and it connects to the inductive current sensor, to measure the current on one of the phases.

The properties of this component are as follows:

- It has 4 leads.
- The two input leads (which connect to the sensor) measure almost 0 Ω resistance and 0 V in diode mode.
- The two output leads (which connect to a voltage divider then an ADC chip) measure 265 to 268 Ω resistance and 0.255 V on the diode mode, both ways.
- There's no continuity between the input and output.

As far as I can tell, this seems like an isolation transformer for this input. Is it simply that?

I need to replace a couple of these components, so I need to know the right name and manufacturer so I can order some. Googling what was written on them (P&V 100487) didn't help.

The component size is around 8 x 15 x 15 mm.

I don't have a tool to measure inductance.

[image: component 8n red]

[image: component on side]

[image: component in black]

Comment: Maybe a transformer. My first thought was relay, but that doesn't make sense with the measurements you took. "24/18" and "13/18" are probably date codes; 24th / 13th week of 2018.

Comment: Yes they are probably date codes that's cause they are different on on other similar components, it's most likely an isolation transformer but i need a way to reorder it. A company code or something

Comment: Probably a proprietary part. A google search comes up with a [magnetics manufacturer](https://pvelektronic.com/en/) by that name. Your best bet is asking them I think.

Comment: That's a good lead , thanks. I hope i can find some kind of catalog of their products